# How do I tell Spring to ignore a setter?

Tags: spring, javabeans, setter, autowired

I have a bean `foo` which has a setter and a couple of `@Autowired` fields. With the setter, I define which validator to use at runtime.

My problem: I define the available validators in Spring, too.

That means: As soon as I try to instantiate `foo`, I get an error that there are several beans which implement `IValidator` and Spring can't decide which one to use to call my setter. Duh.

Is there a way to tell Spring "ignore this setter"?

**[EDIT]** The code is really simple:

```
public class AutowireTestBean {

    // Required bean without setter
    @Autowired
    private TestBean autowired;
    public TestBean getAutowired() {
        return autowired;
    }

    // Standard setter. If this bean is missing, nothing bad happens
    private OptionalBean optional;
    public void setOptional( OptionalBean optional ) {
        this.optional = optional;
    }
    public OptionalBean getOptional() {
        return optional;
    }
}
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
       default-autowire="byType"
       default-lazy-init="true">

    <bean id="bean" class="AutowireTestBean" />

    <bean id="autowired" class="TestBean" />
    <bean id="optional1" class="OptionalBean" />
    <bean id="optional2" class="OptionalBean" />

    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

This throws: `UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bean' ... expected single matching bean but found 2: [optional1, optional2]`

Comment: Why would Spring call this setter if you haven't marked it with @Autowired? Could you share your code?

Comment: Because Spring works with beans. Internally, it also uses `java.beans.Introspector`. @Autowired is only necessary when working with private fields that have no setter or when you work with constructor arguments.

Comment: It sounds like a job for `@Qualifier`, but without seeing the code, it is difficult to tell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Qualifier` on the `OptionalBean` member:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("optional1")  // or optional2
private OptionalBean optional;
```

or on the setter:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("optional1")  // or optional2
public void setOptional( OptionalBean optional ) {
    this.optional = optional;
}
```

Comment: It also works if I add `@Qualifier("do not call me")` (i.e. a qualifier which you can't use in XML). Is that safe? It would state my intent more clearly. But I guess I can also define a "defaultOptional" bean :-/

Comment: Also note that the `@Autowired` is optional in this case because Spring by default calls all the setters it can find. `@Autowired` is only necessary if there is no setter (private fields).

Comment: I am curious, what Spring construct/definition is causing this to happen (the automatic autowiring of public setters)?  Is it the `default-autowire="byType"`?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild: yes. I tested it, and removing the default-autowire makes Spring autowire only the fields/methods/constructors annotated with Autowired. I was also curious, because by default, setters are not automatically called.

Comment: @JBNizet: I was going to provide an edit to my answer asking where the asker configures the setter of AutowireBean...but they addressed my concern in their comments, and I assumed they knew something I didn't. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `default-autowire="byType"` from your XML file.

In this case, only annotations will be used to wire the beans, and thus only setters marked with `@Autowired` will be called by Spring.

Comment: That does fix this error but breaks the annotation `@Required` :-(

Comment: Add Autowired where you have Required. Or better, use Autowired(required = true)